# Why doesn't nextLine() wait for input consistently in my Java program?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, getter-setter

I have a Java program with a model class utilizing getters/setters that build objects that are stored in an ArrayList. In these objects are a firstName, lastName, address, and PIN.

This is the code in the model class, followed by the code in another class for building these objects:

model class:

```
public class AccountCreator {

// variables
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
private int PIN = 0;
private double balance = 0;

// giving object sane name
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

// set
public void setFirstName(String first) {
    firstName = first;
}

public void setLastName(String last) {
    lastName = last;
}

public void setAddress(String addr) {
    address = addr;
}

public int setPIN() {
    PIN = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
    return PIN;
}

// get
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public int getPIN() {
    return PIN;
}
}
```

Code for adding objects to list:

```
private ArrayList<AccountCreator> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner accScan = new Scanner(System.in);
AccountCreator account = new AccountCreator();
System.out.println("Please enter the following account details: ");
System.out.println("First name: ");
account.setFirstName(accScan.nextLine());
System.out.println("Last name: ");
account.setLastName(accScan.nextLine());
System.out.println("Full address: ");
account.setAddress(accScan.nextLine());
account.setPIN();
System.out.println("New account PIN is: " + account.getPIN());
```

As you can see, I use Scanner to get input for all the object details, and I use .nextLine() so I can catch full addresses and multiple surnames.

Later, I have code which looks into the ArrayList and edits the details of already stored objects. This is that code:

```
int c = accScan.nextInt();
for (int d = 0; d < accountList.size(); d++) {
if (c == d) {
       System.out.println(accountList.get(c));
       System.out.println("First name: " + accountList.get(c).getFirstName());
       System.out.println("Last name: " + accountList.get(c).getLastName());
       System.out.println("Full address: " + accountList.get(c).getAddress());
       System.out.println("PIN number: " + accountList.get(c).getPIN());
       TextSpacer();
  }
 }
```

The issue is that when I try to edit the stored objects, the program does not correctly wait for my input and the object's data becomes a mess. This doesn't happen if I only use .next(), but that is not a solution. I don't understand why nextLine() works when creating the object, but not edit it.

**Edit:** After following [this answer by Rohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo/13102066#13102066), I placed `accScan.nextLine();` after the line `int m = accScan.nextInt();` in my code, which has addressed the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A good thing to learn here (if you want to post good questions that aren’t too hard for people to answer) is [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OleV.V. that is definitely something I struggle with. Thank you for your suggestion. As for being a duplicate, none of the duplicate questions I read seemed to provide an exact solution.

Comment: Not? Did you try both suggested solutions in [this answer by Rohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/5772882) with your line `int c = accScan.nextInt();`, for example? If so, please edit your question and report the results and I will be happy to reopen.

Comment: I have followed Rohit's solution and it seems to have worked, though I do not entirely understand why. This is due to my own limited grasp of programming though.